# AttributeError: module 'discord' has no attribute 'Bot'

Tags: discord.py, attributeerror

When I run my code I get this error:

```
 File "main.py", line 16, in <module>
   bot = discord.Bot(command_prefix = "lol");
AttributeError: module 'discord' has no attribute 'Bot'
```

I am not totally sure what I have to change to get it to run either. Does someone happen to know what to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to use the commands extension, you want to put `from discord.ext import commands` at the top of your code. Then, change `discord.Bot` to `commands.Bot`.

Comment: It worked! Thank you!